# Algebraic normalisation of regularity structures: can there be a explicit expression of g?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-differential-equations, regularity-structures

This is related to [Bruned, Hairer, and Zambotti - *Algebraic renormalisation of regularity structures*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.08468). In the method of re-normalization the functional $g$ shown in page 6 plays a major role. However, in the paper there is no explicit expression of $g$ shown (as an example for particular PDE). Is there any reference where I can find such example? Any comment or suggestion?

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you are asking. The $g$ can be any functional . It is example of functional operating under the model of regular structure, not related to any PDE.